# How do I create an archive of all files beginnning with g in current directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I have tried

```
find / -name g* | cpio -ov > gArch
```

But it is not working, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This forum is for coding help.  Try https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `tar cf myarchive.tar g*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated already, this is more for [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com), but anyway:

`find . -name 'g*' | cpio -ov > arch.cpio`